# How do I get different numbers every time I run this c++ program?

Tags: c++

I am using rand() to generate a random number and display it in the context of an arithmetic problem. I get the same two numbers everytime. How do I make these different each time?

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int numberOne = rand()%1000;
    int numberTwo = rand()%1000;
    int numberThree = numberOne + numberTwo;
    char input;

    cout  << " " << numberOne << endl;
    cout <<  "+" << numberTwo << endl;
    cout << "----";
    cin.get();
    cout << numberThree << endl;
}
```

Comment: `srand` with `time` ?

Comment: Notice now we have `<random>` facilities to replace `srand`/`rand`.

Comment: @Jarod42 -- notice how using `<random>` facilities to replace `srand/rand` doesn't affect the problem in the slightest. The seeding issue is still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    /* initialize random seed: */
    srand (time(NULL));

    int numberOne = rand()%1000;
    int numberTwo = rand()%1000;
    int numberThree = numberOne + numberTwo;
    char input;

    cout  << " " << numberOne << endl;
    cout <<  "+" << numberTwo << endl;
    cout << "----";
    cin.get();
    cout << numberThree << endl;
}
```

In order for you to get a random number you need to provide a seed.